# Can i call a function with ng-if?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was curious about something. I've been browsing through the docs for angular and other place on the web but I can't find an instance of where this may be used, so I assume I can't I just want to make sure.

I have HTML that calls my function in javascript like so. All my function does is return a simple string for now. It will return 'test'.

```
<div class="class" ng-if="test.test != originOf.function.test()"></div>
```

Is this possible? I feel like it's not and I really just want it to work

Comment: it is about Angular 2

Comment: Yes you can, also in angular 1

Comment: Assuming your variables are all correct, I see no reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Awesome thank you guys! I'm glad I am not completely crazy then. I must have something mixed up somewhere then.

Comment: The answer to almost all "is it possible" questions is "try it and see". This would be pretty easy to test...

Comment: Ya I just had a mix up with some of my naming conventions. oops. sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 3):

**Yup... 100% working!**

> As long as this expression returns a boolean you can do anything with
>   it.

```
ng-if="test.test != originOf.function.test()"
```

Comment: `as long as...` you don't specifically need for a returned boolean, in javascript you can pass whatever you want in an `if` statement.

Comment: Ahh dude! it is an if statement of a kind so at the very bottom it boils down to a true or false, if something is present or not, boolean... Its a very generic answer...
and yes we can pass everything don't mean that we should.
@angular-typescript best practices

Comment: *As long as this expression returns a boolean you can do anything with it* is wrong, as I said, you don't specifically need for a Boolean because under the hood everything will be casted to a Boolean. Yours isn't a generic answer because you mentioned `Boolean` which is a `Type`, you should have said `value`, this, for example, is a perfect valid if statement `if({})`.